# Delay in AUGraph callback

Tags: cocoa, core-audio, audiounit

We are developing a music player app for Lion OSX(10.7), which applies different audio effects to selected music file.
We have used Audio unit and AUGraph APi's to achieve this.
However after connecting all the audio unit node , when we call AUGraphStart(mGraph) graph takes around 1 sec to invoke first I/o callback.
Because of this there is slight delay in the beginning of the playback.
How can we avoid this delay?Could any one provide any imputs to help us solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to start the audio graph running before displaying any UI that the user could use to start playback.  Since the audio units will then be running, you could fill any audio output buffers with silence before the appropriate UI event.  If the buffers are small/short, the latency from any UI event till an output buffer is filled may be small enough to be below normal human perception.